# EnableRaisingEvents выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, windows, события

Здравствуйте, я хочу получать уведомления о записи новых событий в журнал "Безопасность", но возникает ошибка доступа к реестру. Ругается именно из-за log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
    class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string logName = "Security";
        EventLogPermission eventLogPerm = new EventLogPermission(EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer, ".");
        EventLog log = new EventLog(logName, ".");
        log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        Console.WriteLine(log.EnableRaisingEvents);
        log.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWritten);

    } 

    public static void OnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Entry.Message);
    }

}
}
```

В результате возникает следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
Необработанное исключение: System.Security.SecurityException: Запрошенный доступ к реестру запрещен.
    в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
    в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Exists(String logName, String machineName)
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForRead(String currentMachineName)
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.get_EntryCount()
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.StartListening(String currentMachineName, String currentLogName)
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.StartRaisingEvents(String currentMachineName, String currentLogName)
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
    в System.Diagnostics.EventLog.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
    в ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) в 
     d:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:строка 21
```

При запуске с правами администратора в консоль выводит true, но в журнале событий "Приложение" регистрируется ошибка:

```
  Имя сбойного приложения: ConsoleApplication1.exe, версия: 1.0.0.0, метка времени: 0x5930ed5c
  Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 10.0.15063.296, метка времени: 0x28e9cf15
  Код исключения: 0xe0434352
  Смещение ошибки: 0x000eb802
  Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x370c
  Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d2db5c98bdd068
  Путь сбойного приложения: 
  D:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1
   \bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe
  Путь сбойного модуля: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
  Идентификатор отчета: 9f82e369-4395-4d8f-a7f1-602d431a4870
  Полное имя сбойного пакета: 
  Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:
```

а также еще одна, такая же как выводилась в консоли

Comment: Добавте сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @0xdb, добавила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программу нужно запускать с правами администратора

Добавь в Properties\app.manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: тогда при запуске регистрируется ошибка в журнале событий

Comment: обновлено......

Comment: Как раз читала этот ответ на Ваш вопрос, спасибо! Вроде помогло :)

Comment: Сначала включила поддержку ClickOnce, не помогло, потом отключила, и исправила созданный файлик манифеста, добавив строку выше из коммента в сам код